# Duplicating working iOS6-Xcode 4.6.3 project for a iOS7-Xcode 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to duplicate a working iOS6 project so I can further develop it in iOS7. One copy is meant for running in Xcode 4.6.3 on iPhone 4, the other will only be used for development with Xcode 5.0 on iPhone5. However even before I started with iOS7/Xcode 5.0 I hit problems.

After I manually backed up project files I soon discovered Xcode 4.6.3 was unable to find the Info.plist file in either copy of the Xcode project because the file's previous directory path no longer matched the new directory path exactly.

So I restored the old directory path and relaunched the project in Xcode and restored classes and supporting files manually using the project navigation window. However this hasn't restored the project to its previous state.

Instead the only scheme my project will now allow is "My Mac 64-bit". Moreover the build, clean and run functions are disabled. It's very upset. Is there something I've missed in Xcode that would make migrating to iOS7 easier ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do this. You use the latest version of Xcode to develop on all platforms. Move your project to Xcode 5 and use only this. You will only be able to submit your apps compiled with 7.0 BASE SDK anyway.

Xcode 4.6.3 project open perfectly well in Xcode 5. You've probably done something wrong in your manual backup and restore process.

If you want to support older iOS versions, then set your deployment target to a lower value.

If you want to support iPhone 4 sized screens, then look into using autolayout in your views.

Comment: Bandejapaisa, you've inspired confidence. A previous project had the storyboard layout messed up, with buttons and text fields hidden but not missing. I managed to edit them by tinkering with the XML script. I imagined I might salvage this project by editing XML in the .xproj file but better to take your advice and hopefully avoid such problems. Thanks

Comment: Generally xib files are not compatible between versions. When I open Xcode 4.6.3 xib files in Xcode 5, it asks me if I want to convert them to the new format - this renders them incompatible with older version of Xcode. I don't have experience of this with storyboards, but I imagine it is the same. Look forward and say bye to Xcode 4 - Xcode 5 has some great new productivity features.